# ChromeDriver in Fullscreen Mode

Tags: selenium, fullscreen, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to send F11 to ChromeDriver, however it does not respond to it.  When I press F11, it turns Chrome into fullscreen mode.  When I send F11 through ChromeDriver, it does not.  This is the same for any F-key in ChromeDriver.  It works fine with FirefoxDriver and IEDriver, just not ChromeDriver.  Is there any way I could get ChromeDriver into fullscreen mode ?

Note : Fullscreen mode is different from maximized mode, as it hides all toolbars.

Comment: the work around i did for this issue, is that right after launching chrome i check the active window title (using user32 lib) and once made sure it is chrome, i dispath native keyboard event F11 which is fired globally, since chrome is in focus, the browser goes in the full screen mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve it using kiosk mode, which keeps the browser in full screen

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--kiosk");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

if you use RemoteWebDriver:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    Instance = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(<SeleniumServerURL>), capabilities);
```

Comment: just a side note, this will lunch it on full-screen WITHOUT browser header area and tabs displayed

Answer (score 8):

The argument is changed:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

Another option is change the startup script of google-chrome, set `start-maximized` as default.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```

Comment: Hi user3759810, welcome to StackOverflow!
Feel free to add more context to your answer. Code-only answer as not as helpful as code with comments.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i fix the differences between selenium webdriver coordinates and screen absolute coordinates (root cause: chrome tab, header and address field size are ignored by selenium .getcoordinate mechanism) by this way:

```
String shortcutGoToFullScreen = Keys.chord(Keys.F11);
WebDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(shortcutGoToFullScreen);
```

*Only one problem, that this fullscreen mode became non full after any page code updates. So, it should be used carefully )*

Answer (score 0):

Use `--start-fullscreen` argument to Specify the browser should start in fullscreen mode, like if the user had pressed F11 right after startup.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can change the behavior as you prefer by providing arguments to ChromeOptions.

Following link gives you in detail view of arguments and their behaviour. Hope it helps.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#start-fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell/Selenium I wrote the script:

```
$Driver = Start-SeChrome -Fullscreen -StartUrl "https://........."
```

This worked perfectly for me