# How do I make selenium chrome open in full screen?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Is there anyway to make selenium open in fullscreen? No need to add any code as this is just a question not really an issue with my code. I need to make it go fullscreen because an element will only load if it's in fullscreen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChromeDriver in Fullscreen Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486442/chromedriver-in-fullscreen-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create WebDriver instance with respectful option

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

or just call `driver.maximize_window()` to maximize already opened Chrome window